# Python argparse positional arguments and sub-commands

Tags: python, argparse, python-2.6, subcommand, python-3.1

I'm working with argparse and am trying to mix sub-commands and positional arguments, and the following issue came up.

This code runs fine:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser.add_argument('positional')
subparsers.add_parser('subpositional')

parser.parse_args('subpositional positional'.split())
```

The above code parses the args into `Namespace(positional='positional')`, however when I change the positional argument to have nargs='?' as such:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser.add_argument('positional', nargs='?')
subparsers.add_parser('subpositional')

parser.parse_args('subpositional positional'.split())
```

It errors out with:

```
usage: [-h] {subpositional} ... [positional]
: error: unrecognized arguments: positional
```

Why is this?

Comment: Btw, seems a [known bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue9340), that has been fixed for recent Python versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first I thought the same as jcollado, but then there's the fact that, if the subsequent (top level) positional arguments have a specific `nargs` (`nargs` = `None`, `nargs` = integer), then it works as you expect. It fails when `nargs` is `'?'` or `'*'`, and sometimes when it is `'+'`. So, I went down to the code, to figure out what is going on.

It boils down to the way the arguments are split to be consumed. To figure out who gets what, the call to `parse_args` summarizes the arguments in a string like `'AA'`, in your case (`'A'` for positional arguments, `'O'` for optional), and ends up producing a regex pattern to be matched with that summary string, depending on the actions you've added to the parser through the `.add_argument` and `.add_subparsers` methods.

In every case, for you example, the argument string ends up being `'AA'`. What changes is the pattern to be matched (you can see the possible patterns under `_get_nargs_pattern` in `argparse.py`. For `subpositional` it ends up being `'(-*A[-AO]*)'`, which means *allow one argument followed by any number of options or arguments*. For `positional`, it depends on the value passed to `nargs`:

- `None` => `'(-*A-*)'`
- 3 => `'(-*A-*A-*A-*)'` (one `'-*A'` per expected argument)
- `'?'` => `'(-*A?-*)'`
- `'*'` => `'(-*[A-]*)'`
- `'+'` => `'(-*A[A-]*)'`

Those patterns are appended and, for `nargs=None` (your working example), you end up with `'(-*A[-AO]*)(-*A-*)'`, which matches two groups `['A', 'A']`. This way, `subpositional` will parse only `subpositional` (what you wanted), while `positional` will match its action.

For `nargs='?'`, though, you end up with `'(-*A[-AO]*)(-*A?-*)'`. The second group is comprised entirely of **optional** patterns, and `*` being greedy, that means the first group globs everything in the string, ending up recognizing the two groups `['AA', '']`. This means `subpositional` gets two arguments, and ends up choking, of course.

Funny enough, the pattern for `nargs='+'` is `'(-*A[-AO]*)(-*A[A-]*)'`, which works *as long as you only pass one argument*. Say `subpositional a`, as you require at least one positional argument in the second group. Again, as the first group is greedy, passing `subpositional a b c d` gets you `['AAAA', 'A']`, which is not what you wanted.

In brief: a mess. I guess this should be considered a bug, but not sure what the impact would be if the patterns are turned into non-greedy ones...

Comment: Note that, of course, adding the subparsers after all the top level, as suggested by jcollado and argparses documentation, will break the ambiguity and work as intended!

Answer (score 6):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('positional', nargs='?')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparsers.add_parser('subpositional')

print(parser.parse_args(['positional', 'subpositional']))
# -> Namespace(positional='positional')
print(parser.parse_args(['subpositional']))
# -> Namespace(positional=None)
parser.print_usage()
# -> usage: bpython [-h] [positional] {subpositional} ...
```

The common practice is that arguments before the command (on the left side) belong to the main program, after (on the right) -- to the command. Therefore `positional` should go before the command `subpositional`. Example programs: `git`, `twistd`.

Additionally an argument with `narg=?` should probably be an option (`--opt=value`), and not a positional argument.

Comment: What if the subparser had positional arguments? How can we let `print(parser.parse_args(['subpositional', 'subparserarg']))` print: `# -> Namespace(positional=None)`? This should have said that we are selecting the subcommand 'subpositional' with the argument `positional` being optional. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is that when `add_subparsers` is called, a new parameter is added to the original parser to pass the name of the subparser.

For example, with this code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser.add_argument('positional')                                             
subparsers.add_parser('subpositional')                                             

parser.parse_args()
```

You get the following help string:

```
usage: test.py [-h] {subpositional} ... positional

positional arguments:
  {subpositional}
  positional

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
```

Note that `subpositional` is displayed before `positional`. I'd say that what you're looking for is to have the positional argument before the subparser name. Hence, probably what you're looking for is adding the argument before the subparsers:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('positional')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparsers.add_parser('subpositional')

parser.parse_args()
```

The help string obtained with this code is:

```
usage: test.py [-h] positional {subpositional} ...

positional arguments:
  positional
  {subpositional}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
```

This way, you pass first the arguments to the main parser, then the name of the subparser and finally the arguments to the subparser (if any).

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Help truly looks as it should, but in practice - it doesn't change the parsing process.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a mess in Python 3.5.

I suggest to subClass ArgumentParser to keep all the remaining positional arguments, and to deal with them later:

```
import argparse

class myArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
       args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
       args.remaining_positionnals = argv
       return args

parser = myArgumentParser()

options = parser.parse_args()
```

The remaining positional arguments are in the list `options.remaining_positionals`