# How do I add optional positional arguments with subparsers in argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to add a required input file name and an optional output file name to more than one subparser using the argparse module.

Here is my attempt:

```
# test_argparse.py

import argparse

def setup_parser():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test_argparse.py',
                            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                            description='Testing the argparse module.')

    parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser_actionA = subparsers.add_parser('actionA')
    parser_actionB = subparsers.add_parser('actionB')
    parser_actionC = subparsers.add_parser('actionC')

    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs=1, help='input mesh file name')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', help='output mesh file name')

    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = setup_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
```

If I execute this:

```
python test_argparse.py actionA infile outfile
```

it doesn't work, and what I get is:

```
usage: test_argparse.py [-h] [--version]
                    {actionA,actionB,actionC} ... infile [outfile]
test_argparse.py: error: unrecognized arguments: infile
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python argparse - Add argument to multiple subparsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498595/python-argparse-add-argument-to-multiple-subparsers)

Comment: this issue may be more related to [Python argparse positional arguments and sub-commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668519/python-argparse-positional-arguments-and-sub-commands) in which the conclusion seems to be that this behavior is either a bug in argparse or a feature of the greedy pattern matching it uses underneath the covers.

Answer (score 7):

Define a new parser with common arguments and pass it to subparsers as [parents](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#parents):

```
files = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
files.add_argument('infile', nargs=1, help='input mesh file name')
files.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', help='output mesh file name')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_actionA = subparsers.add_parser('actionA', parents=[files])
parser_actionB = subparsers.add_parser('actionB', parents=[files])
etc..
```

Comment: Is `parser` correct in your example?  If I define `files` as you have, then `parser` "is not defined".  Should it be `files` instead?

Comment: @harperville: yes, it's correct. This snippet extends the OP's code, where they have `parser` defined.

Comment: The `add_help` directive was key to allowing me to continue in my quest to get this to work.  Thanks for this answer.